# Loading file not working

Tags: visual-c++

whenever I use the loadGame function I have created, it does not display the data I have previously stored in the file. When I check the file it is all there. I tried using global varies and local variables but neither worked.

```css
// Arena RPG.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// Created by Logan Daniels

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Prototypes
void introScreen();
string loadGame();
string newGame(string, string, string);
int exit();

//constant global Variables
const string knight = "Knight";
const string mage = "Mage";
const string assasin = "Assasin";
string name, equipment, characterClass;
string gold;


int main()
{
 introScreen();


    return 0;
}

void introScreen()
{
 int option;

 cout << "Welcome to Arena!\n"
  << "Please select an option from the list\n"
  << "1.Load\n2.New Game\n3.Exit\n"
  << "Number option: ";
 cin >> option;

 if (option == 1)
  loadGame();
 else if (option == 2)
  newGame(knight, mage, assasin);
 else if (option == 3)
  exit();

}

string newGame(const string knight, const string mage, const string assasin)
{
 system("CLS");

 string name, equipment;
 
 int gold = 100;
 string characterClass; // used in loop

 cout << "Welcome to the character creation menu!\n"
  << "Enter your name\nName: ";
 cin.ignore();
 getline(cin, name);

 cout << "\nPick a class.\n1.Knight, 2.Assasin, 3.Mage\n";
 cin >> characterClass;

 while (characterClass != knight && characterClass != mage && characterClass != assasin)
 {
  cout << "That is an invalid character class\n";
  cout << "\nPick a class.\n1.Knight, 2.Assasin, 3.Mage\n";
  cin >> characterClass;
 }

 system("CLS");

 cout << "Welcome to the arena!\nIts time ot begin your adventure " << name << endl << "Hit enter when redy!\n";

 ofstream saveFile;  //New game file
 saveFile.open("Game Save Data.txt");

 saveFile << name << endl;
 saveFile << characterClass << endl;
 saveFile << gold << endl;
 saveFile << equipment << endl;

 saveFile.close();
 system("pause");
 return name, characterClass, gold, equipment;
}

string loadGame()
{
 string name, characterClass, gold, equipment;

 ifstream saveFile;
 saveFile.open("Game Save Data");

 saveFile >> name;
 cout << name << endl;

 saveFile >> characterClass;
 cout << characterClass << endl;

 saveFile >> gold;
 cout << gold << endl;

 saveFile >> equipment;
 cout << equipment << endl;

 cout << name << endl << characterClass << endl << gold << endl << equipment << endl;
 system("pause");
 
 return name, equipment, characterClass, gold;
}

int exit()
{
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing to "Game Save Data.txt" but trying to open "Game Save Data" (no extension).

Comment: Thanks I realized that when i woke up this morning ;)